# Creating a new boolean column based on another dataframe in Spark

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have a big dataset with many columns:

```
df =

my_id    attr_1    attr_2   ...  attr_n
13900    null      USA           384.24
13900    null      UK            399.24
13999    3467      USA           314.25
13911    3556      CND           386.77
13922    5785      USA           684.21
```

I also have a smaller dataframe whose first column is null:

```
df_2 =

    col_1    col_2
    null     13900
    null     13999
    null     34002
```

I want to add a new column to `df` that indicates whether the respective `my_id` is present is `df_2`:

```
my_id    attr_1    attr_2   ...  attr_n   check
13900    null      USA           384.24   yes
13900    null      UK            399.24   yes
13999    3467      USA           314.25   yes
13911    3556      CND           386.77   no
13922    5785      USA           684.21   no
```

I was thinking of left joining `df_2` to `df`, create a column that is `yes` when `col_2` is populated and `no` when it isn't, and then dropping `col_2`, but is there any more elegant way?

Comment: your idea is the way it should be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct: you can do a `left` join and then using conditional function `when`, derive the column `check` basing on the left-joined column. A sample could could look something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit

# 1. Do a left join
df_3 = df.join(df_2, col("my_id") == col("col_2"), how="left")

# 2. Derive the value of `check` column 
df_3.withColumn("check", when(col("col_2").isNotNull(), lit("yes")).otherwise(lit("no")
```